# Flash: Parsing a JSON file that has a node called Class

Tags: json, flash, actionscript

Essentially I'm trying to parse JSON and assigning the results to variables, one of which is "var = JSON.class;" with class being what's returned in the JSON. However, flash won't let me parse it because it's called class which it uses to create new classes. Is there any workaround or will I not be able to grab this node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you have a property in your JSON object named "class", you should be able to parse it like as shown below.

```
// assuming JSON object looks like this, and is stored in a var named 'jsonData'
var jsonData:Object = { "id": 0, "class": "MyClassName", "values": [1,2,3] }

// trying to parse like this won't work w/keywords like 'class':
var parsedValue : String = jsonData.class;

// parse it with this way, using the square brackets:
var parsedValue : String = jsonData["class"];
```